# VBA - Application.Visible = False on Workbook_Open() does not stay False if another workbook opens

Tags: excel, vba, userform

The code below works fine for hiding the workbook and showing the UserForm on workbook open. But when I open another workbook alongside it the workbook then appears, as if the application.visible is changed to true in the background. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
    UserForm1temp.Show
End Sub
```

Thank you for the help in advance, I will mark correct answers accordingly and accept the final.

Comment: "the workbook then appears" which work book then appears? `ThisWorkbook` or the one you just opened?

Comment: The new one and the one that is hidden

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Although you're putting `ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False`, Excel will not apply this to just `ThisWorkbook`. It will apply it to the whole application. You might have 30 books open, they'll all become hidden as the application itself is hidden. Opening a new book does indeed over-ride this setting though and 'unhides' the application.

Answer (score 1):

Make the window that that the workbook is in invisible as well as the application

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.Visible = False
   ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
   UserForm1.Show
 End Sub
```

Comment: TBH, I'd probably leave the Application visible personally - no telling what the user has done with it...

Comment: Hi this works to an extent but when I close the other workbook the one that is hidden closes too?

Answer (score 0):

A safer approach is to use the WindowState property than using Application.Visible property, if the intent is that user only sees the form. Not a robust solution but get the job done.

```
  Private Sub Workbook_Open()
      Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
      AutomatedEmailSender.Show
   End Sub
```

And then, moving the closing workbook code to the *UserForm_Terminate* event.

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
            ThisWorkbook.Close , False
 End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Application.workbooks.application.visible=false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).